# Java find what JFrame belongs to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a multiple `JPanels` which are put in a dialogue and after many hours, I am still unable to find the frame in which the `JPanels` are stored in. I was wondering if there is a method which would return the `JFrame` (end goal is to call `setDefaultCloseOperation()` on the `JFrame`). I was thinking `getParent()` would do this however I am still unable to call `setDefaultCloseOperation` no matter how many layers of parents I go through.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a utility method for it:
[SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component))

If you add your `JPanel` to a `JFrame`, it will be obviously a `JFrame` instance:

```
JFrame f = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(panel);
```

Note: `getWindowAncestor()` and `windowForComponent()` provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...);
```